# sql character encoding non English character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, encoding, character-encoding, sql-insert

i'm using sql 2008 r2
i'm trying to insert some value in arabic language

```
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num ) values ('مديرية الزراعة/التقانة','235767')
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num) values ('محمد  راتب ابازيد','227927')
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num) values ('فادي مصطفى ابازيد','221355')
```

but the result look like :

```
select * from tbl_number
number_num            number_ownerName 
235767          ?????? ???????/??????? 
227927                  ????  ???? ??????    
221355                  ???? ????? ??????
```

Comment: What's the column type and collation?

Comment: Also make sure to use the `N` prefix for wide character constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for **[NCHAR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)** which is NATIONAL CHAR that is stored as UTF-16LE and is the only way to reliably store non-ASCII characters.

> Fixed-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must
>   be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is two times n
>   bytes. When the collation code page uses double-byte characters, the
>   storage size is still n bytes. Depending on the string, the storage
>   size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n. The ISO
>   synonyms for nchar are national char and national character..

Also note that **SQL Server has no support for UTF-8.**

Also check

- [Using SQL Server Collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Storing and Retrieving Non-English Unicode Characters (Hindi, Czech,
  Arabic etc.) in SQL Server](http://aalamrangi.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/storing-and-retrieving-non-english-unicode-characters-hindi-czech-arabic-etc-in-sql-server/)

**EDIT:-**

As commented, you can add N while you are inserting. Try like this:

```
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num ) values (N'مديرية الزراعة/التقانة','235767') 
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num) values (N'محمد راتب ابازيد','227927') 
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num) values (N'فادي مصطفى ابازيد','221355')
```

Comment: thank you Rahul Tripathi , I changed to NCHAR but the same result
when i tried to insert values from "edit top 200 Rows" it be OK and no problem with encoding :(

Comment: thanks its solved I just add 'N

    insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num ) values (N'مديرية الزراعة/التقانة','235767')
    insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num) values ('محمد  راتب ابازيد','227927')
insert into tbl_number (number_ownerName , number_num) values (N'فادي مصطفى ابازيد','221355')

Comment: @Fadi It looks like you didn't add enough `N`s to all the right places there. Both values should get the `N`. Unless the display of mixed RTL and LTR is messing with what I think I see, in which case I apologise.